# How to use data from WHERE query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM A

LEFT JOIN B
ON B.id = A.id

LEFT JOIN C
ON C.other = A.other

WHERE

(SELECT SUM(C.quantity) FROM C WHERE C.other = A.other) < A.quantity
```

Is any way to get values from SELECT from WHERE clause? For example for PHP to use? Something like:

```
WHERE

(SELECT SUM(C.quantity) FROM C WHERE C.other = A.other) AS quantity < A.quantity
```

I need to compare this two values in mysql and then i need them both in my script. I can of course put this subquery into first SELECT - but i belive there is better way to do this than repeat code in many places.

Comment: If you need the results of the subquery, you can JOIN to it instead; an INNER JOIN will make it filter in the same way the WHERE does. _(Though you will want to alias it's result, and maybe alias the different references to C to make the query more readable, since it is a correlated subquery using the same table as the outer query)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that as follows:

```
SELECT    A.*, B.*, C.*, D.sumq 
FROM      A
LEFT JOIN B
       ON B.id = A.id
LEFT JOIN C
       ON C.other = A.other
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT   other, SUM(quantity) sumq
           FROM     C
           GROUP BY other
          ) AS D
       ON D.other = A.other
WHERE     COALESCE(D.sumq, 0) < A.quantity
```